# save collection in global variable in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, variables, eloquent

so basically i have an index page where i have to go to controller to fetch data from database

route:-

```
route::get('/index/{$x}', 'indexController@index');
```

index controller:-

`$data = Data::where('name', $x)->get();
return View::make('index', compact('data');`

then inside index page i have link that goes to second page 
with same data,  i d not want to query the same data as it may affect performance

route:-

```
route::get('/second', indexController@second);});
```

Second Controller:-

`$data = $data->sortBy('id');
return View::make('second', compact('data');`

i thought of saving data in global variable in controller

so i added private variable inside controller and try to access it through `$this->data`

but it did not work cause based on my search the controller will be closed after it returns view

so if i try access `$this->data` inside second function it will be empty

is it possible to save queried data (collection) in global variable

as i do not want to query same data for every page

your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you having same data on different pages that will not be solved using any kind of global variables. You need to cache query results. Please check cache in laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/cache

Here is how that is usually done:

```
$data = Cache::get('some_cache_key');

if (empty($data)) {
    $data = Data::where('name', $x)->get();
    Cache::put('some_cache_key', $data, 60); //60 minutes
}

return View::make('index', compact('data');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. Either you can store the data in the `Session` and access all across the application

```
$data = Data::where('name', $x)->get();

session()->put('data', $data);
```

You can also use `View::share('key', $data)`

In your `AppServiceProvider` inside `boot()` method

```
 public function boot()
    {            
        View::share('data', Cache::get('data'));
    }
```

In your controller.

```
$data = Data::where('name', $x)->get();
Cache::put('data', $data);
```

By this way you can access the data all across the application using `{{ $data }}` in your views.

hope this helps.